# Can a language have more than one DFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

For Example when we consider a DFA that allows the strings having neither sub strings `00` or `11` I can produce the following two DFAs:

[image]

Answer (score 39):

First of all, your left DFA is incorrect - it accepts e.g. 011.

Secondly, DFAs can be [canonically minimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization), so in that sense, you can always find one canonical DFA for a certain language.

But in general, there are infinitely many different DFAs for every language, so you could get different correct answers.

Comment: And that's even infinitely many up to isomorphism.

Comment: To be even more specific: it's infinite up to isomorphism when the states are a subset of a fixed set, e.g. $\mathbb{N}$. If we don't fix that, the collection of automata is not even a set... Somehow I don't think this was the intention of the OP :)

Comment: Infinitely many different DFAs even for finite languages?

Comment: @Bergi : Certainly - you can add as many redundant states as you like. This may sound "silly", and it is indeed senseless when you construct an automaton yourself. However, many times automata are constructed by translating from some other formalism (e.g. determinization of NFAs), in which case you are very likely to get redundant states.

Comment: @Shaull: You mean with ε-transitions or unreachable states? OK, I didn't consider those.

Comment: No $\epsilon$-transitions. Just add useless states. For example, instead of having a self-loop, you could have an arbitrarily long chain, and then a self loop.

Comment: After removing useless states (i.e. from which no acccepting state can be reached), only one DFA (up to isomorphism) remains for each finite language. Infinite languages have infinitely many  non-isomorphic DFAs even without useless states.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get different DFAs for a particular language, these differences often arise in the inclusion or exclusion of certain inputs. Redundant inputs don't negate the validity of DFAs as long as it's correctly accepting the strings in it's accept state & there are no two inputs path on a vertice in the transition diagram-- the main reason
of the DFA.
So keep cool, if you got an entirely different transition diagram different from that of your professor’s as long as the language gets accepted you're good to go